# vaadin how to selectivly put checkbox on treetable

Tags: java, vaadin

Hi below link from Vaadin you can see how to set checkboxes on tabletree, But I don't want all of the nodes have a checkbox but only a string, only some of them. is that possible to set that?

[vaadin treetable example url](http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples/book/#component.treetable.components)

Comment: What happens if you pass null instead of CheckBox object

Comment: @fmucar but i want a title there?

Comment: You can try to make the class Component for that column in the container and add CheckBox or Label or other components whichever you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fmucar tell the answer, you can do that, by adding a generated column in your treeTable like this

```
treeTable.addGeneratedColumn("generated", new ColumnGenerator() {

@Override
public Component generateCell(Table source, final Object itemId, Object columnId){

    // Get the object associated with the row
    Object Objet = source.getItem(itemId);

    //Missing casting instruction

    if(your condition to check to render a CheckBox()){
       return new CheckBox();
    }

    return new Label("your text");
}
```

});

Regards